# Using VBA to relink a table, unassigns table from Custom group

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using Access. I have external linked tables to a backend database. If I use the 'Linked Table Manager' to relink my tables, it properly completes the action and leaves the tables grouped in the navigation pane.

I've reduced the code below to what I believe is the problem. RefreshLink is removing the linked table from a navigation pane group.

CODE:

```
For each tdf in CurrentDB.TableDefs
     If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
          tdf.refreshlink
     End If
Next
```

How can I relink tables, with VBA and preserve the Navigation groups?

Thank you.

Comment: May be out of luck. I've never bothered with custom grouping.